# Second moment and distribution of $Z=IX+(1-I)Y$ with $I\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

Let $Z=IX+(1-I)Y$ with $I\sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$ and $I,X,Y$ independent.

> I want to determine the expected value of $Z^2$:

Using independence of $X,Y,I$ and linearity I arrive at:

$\begin{equation}E[Z^2]=\underbrace{E[I^2]}_{=p}E[X^2]+2E[X]E[Y]\underbrace{E[I(1-I)]}_{=p-p=0}+\underbrace{E[(1-I)^2]}_{=1-2p+p=1-p}E[Y^2]\end{equation}$

Is that correct?

> Now assume $X,Y$ are i.i.d $\mathcal N(0,1)$.
> How can I determine the distribution of $Z$?

I thought about using the mgf:

$m_Z(t)=E[e^{tIX}e^{tY}e^{-IY}]$ but I think this doesn't work out because $e^{tY}$ and $e^{-IY}$ aren't independent. So I need help with this task. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p)$, then $I^2 = I$ identically, and we immediately have $$Z^2 = I^2 X^2 + 2I(1-I)XY + (1-I)^2 Y^2 = IX^2 + (1-I)Y^2,$$ hence $$\operatorname{E}[Z^2] = p \operatorname{E}[X^2] + (1-p) \operatorname{E}[Y^2].$$

If $X, Y$ are IID standard normal, then conditioned on $I$, $$Z \mid I = IX + (1-I)Y \mid I \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = I^2 + (1-I)^2).$$  But since we already stated above that $I^2 = I$, this illustrates that the conditional distribution of $Z \mid I$ is standard normal irrespective of $I$.  So the unconditional distribution of $Z$ is also standard normal.

Another way to conceptualize this is to note that we may equivalently write $$Z \mid I = \begin{cases} X, & I = 1 \\ Y, & I = 0 \end{cases}$$ and since $X$ and $Y$ are IID standard normal, it doesn't matter what value $I$ takes on.  MGF calculations are unnecessary.

What $Z$ basically represents is "flip a coin that has probability $p$ of being heads.  If it's heads, then pick standard normal $X$ as the value of $Z$.  If it's tails, then pick standard normal $Y$ as the value of $Z$."  Since you're always picking from a standard normal random variable, the coin flip doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer is correct but this method is faster:

The rv Z is the following

$$Z =
\begin{cases}
X,  & p \\
Y, & (1-p)
\end{cases}$$

Thus the second moment is simply

$$\mathbb{E}[Z^2]=p\mathbb{E}[X^2]+(1-p)\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$$

For the same reason, Z density is a mixture of two iid Standard gaussian

$$f_Z(z)=p\cdot \phi(z)+(1-p)\phi(z)=\phi(z)$$

....in other words

$$Z\sim N(0;1)$$